# Questions regarding JWT Authentication with OAuth Login in .net WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, jwt

I wanted to implement OAuth LogIn with something like google with JWT without .NET identity but the AddOAuth() package only add it to a cookie. What I learned so far the flow without AddOAuth() would be like this:

1. User clicks on the client login with Google.
2. Frontend calls the API endpoint backend.com/api/login-google.
3. The Endpoint redirect to google's login screen with client id/secret/scope.
4. Google redirect to API's Endpoint (backend.com/api/google-redirect) with a code
5. The API uses the code to get an AccessToken
6. With the AccessToken the API requests Google's User information defined in the scope. If the AccessToken is correct, Google returns the user's info.
7. The Backend Registers the user and generates a JWT with the information it got from Google.

Is this correct? is there a built in way or to do so?

I found a bit complicated way to do it in AddOAuth() configuration but I'm not sure if this is a better practice than implementing it using Api endpoints?

```
    services.AddCookie("Google-Cookie")
            .AddOAuth("Google",
                options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Google-Cookie";
                    options.ClientId = configuration["ClientId"]>;
                    options.ClientSecret = configuration["ClientSecret"];

                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
                    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
                    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";

                    options.CallbackPath = "/api/Google-Redirect";


                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("read:user");
                    options.SaveTokens = true; // Not sure what does this do 

                    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                    {
                        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                        using var result = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request);
                        var user = await result?.Content?.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonElement>();
                        context.RunClaimActions(user); // I don't think this is needed


                        // Create claims for the token
                        var claims = new Claim[]
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
                        };

                        // Create the token
                        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                            issuer: configuration["JWT_Issuer"],
                            audience: configuration["JWT_Audience"],
                            claims: claims,
                            expires:  DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);,
                            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT_Secret"]));, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                        );
                        // Generate the token string
                        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
                        context.Response.Cookies.Append("X-Access-Token", tokenString, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict });

                    };
                }
    );
```

As for the JWT is the refresh token a JWToken? or is it just a random string? should I do anything else to that string, should I encrypt it before saving it to the database? If I'm going to use an HTTPOnly cookie should I put the Refresh token in it or the access token or both? I was thinking about keeping refresh token in HTTPOnly token and the send the access token in the response body with the claims

I'm using this flow to implement authentication without identity

1. User sends his username and password
2. I Copied [Identity's hashing methods](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs), it returns a hashed+salted password to store in the database
3. The method compares the password's hash with the database salt
4. I generate a JWT access and refresh token.

The AddOAuth() implementation seems to convoluted a bit and it adds a separate cookie I'm not sure how to stop it from generating that cookie since I'm not using it. Should I implement the flow myself as I mentioned above or keep using the AddOAuth() with this implementation?

Edit : I Added the "google-cookie"as just a workaround to make the AddOAuth() work. Just to test it out.

I started with implementing authenticating using JWT. Then I wanted to add OAuth to enable Login using Google/Github etc.

When a user sign in using Google, I just want google to verify he is who say he is to login but still keep my JWT flow, buth AddOAuth requires a cookie that's why I added the AddCookie and `options.SignInScheme = "Google-Cookie";` wouldn't work when I make it Bearer

````
The registered sign-in schemes are: X-Access-Token."```


This is why I'm asking if I'm doing AddOAuth wrong? should I keep it customized like it is? should I just go with my own implementation based on that flow above?
````

Comment: If you're using Google to authenticate users then don't try to use the OAuth libraries directly, instead use the premade `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google

Comment: @Dai Thank you, I'm using Google as in example though, it could be anything that doesn't have a premade package.